# SQL Server: Insert special or escape characters into text column

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2014

I have a python code that generates below insert statement, which seems to have special or escaping characters (marked with ). I have set the Quote Identifier off before this insert statement but yet I am getting the below error.

SQL Statements:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

INSERT into PREDICTIVE_HIST_EXTIMES VALUES ('002775',"ccollections
defaultdict
p1
(c__builtin__
list
p2
tRp3
cdatetime
date
p4
(S'\x07\xe0\x01\x0b'
tRp5
(lp6
cnumpy.core.multiarray
scalar
p7
(cnumpy
dtype
p8
(S'i8'
I0
I1
tRp9
(I3
S'<'
NNNI-1
I-1
I0
tbS'\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tRp10
ag7
(g8
(S'f8'
I0
I1
tRp11
(I3
S'<'
NNNI-1
I-1
I0
tbS'\xecQ\xb8\x1e%"\xf0@'
tRp12
asg4
(S'\x07\xe0\x01\x06'
tRp13
(lp14
g7
(g9
S'\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tRp15
ag7
(g11
S'\xecQ\xb8\x1e%"\xf0@'
tRp16
asg4
(S'\x07\xe0\x01\x08'
tRp17
(lp18
g7
(g9
S'\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tRp19
ag7
(g11
S'\xecQ\xb8\x1e%"\xf0@'
tRp20
asg4
(S'\x07\xe0\x01\x07'
tRp21
(lp22
g7
(g9
S'\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tRp23
ag7
(g11
S'\xecQ\xb8\x1e%"\xf0@'
tRp24
asg4
(S'\x07\xe0\x01\x12'
tRp25
(lp26
g7
(g9
S'\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
tRp27
ag7
(g11
S'>\n\xd7\xa3\x1c\xf9\xeb@'
tRp28
as.")
```

It give below error at this line ***tbS'\xecQ\xb8\x1e%"\xf0@'***

```
Incorrect syntax near '\'.. Error 102. SQLSTATE 42000. Severity 15. MsgState 1. Line 44.
```

The table structure is as below;

```
My_Table
    (
    PERSONS_ID NVARCHAR (510) NULL,
    METRIC_OBJ NVARCHAR (max) NULL
    )
```

I have little control over the contents which goes into the columns. So I cannot replace any single quotes with something else.

Is there any other technique that I can use to insert this text into the METRIC_OBJ column? Should changing the column data type help?

Comment: You're using double-quote  `"` instead  of single-quote `'` `INSERT into PREDICTIVE_HIST_EXTIMES VALUES ('002775',"ccollections  <--`

Comment: The text has single quotes in it, hence the double quotes outside.

Comment: Yes, I've missed SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

Comment: Can you modify the text?  The error is produced by the double-quoted: `tbS'\xecQ\xb8\x1e%"\xf0@' `  --> '"\xf0@''  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b10fe7bc992b4abe09363a50c90f5de6

Comment: Wish I could do that, but I have no control over the text. Cannot even substitute the quotes within the text to something else.

Comment: I suggest you use the sp_execute instead of just EXEC. With the sp_execute you can pass parameters

Comment: Your text has both single and double quotes in it. There is no other way is to contact your python developers to escape either of them

Comment: I changed the python code to use a different type of object to store into tables, that eliminated both the single and double inverted commas. But if anyone finds answer to this, feel free to share for the sake of the community :)